# Harmonic function is generalization of holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

In what context can we say this?

I know that if I have a function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ and express $f=u+iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are the function that sends $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic function. But I don't know how we can say that "harmonic function" is the generalization of "holomorphic function."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Connections_with_complex_function_theory

Does this help?

Comment: Definitely, thanks